# How to set default array property values in class

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, properties

I am wondering what the best way is to set an an array property where some default values are already known, but is able to extend with more values later.

Can you set the values by defining the property like this:

```
class demoClass {

   protected $_config = [
      'key1' => 'value',
      'key2' => 'value'
   ];

}
```

Or do you need a constructor function to set the default values like this:

```
class demoClass {

   protected $_config = [];

   public function __construct() {

      $this->_config = [
         'key1' => 'value',
         'key2' => 'value'
      ];

   }
}
```

Comment: Easy enough for you to check whether the first option works yourself; are any of the values dependent on run-time information?

Comment: i prefer the first choice, because your are working into the OOP philosophy

Comment: If you don't need to add a value in the array during initialization, then I prefer the first option.

Comment: @MarkBaker Both options work for me, but I'm wondering what is the "best" way to do it. In my current situation the values don't depend on run-time information.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón thanks for your comment. Can you explain what you exactly mean with the OOP philosophy in combination with my question?

Comment: Personally, I prefer to keep constructors as empty as possible, especially if the class is open for extension

Comment: @kjames no I don't need to add values during initialization, but would you otherwise set them in the constructor?

Comment: @Robbert in that case, I don't use the constructor.

Comment: your're using class method, and in my mind is OOP philosophy, so i prefer to declare defaults into first definition of paramters and not onto contruct

Comment: There is no "best". It depends on implementation details and personal preference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For clarity I feel that the constructor method is the way to go. You'll get a better overview of available variables when they're defined like that. On the downside is that if you want to change the name of the variable you'll have to change it in two places. However, both will get the job done.